# Flask HTML Template to fill in MySQL records

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, flask

How can I fill in {{ }} in HTML with values from a MySQL DB. The app is written in Flask, Python version 2.7.13.  Flask 0.12.2

when browsing to http://127.0.0.1:5000/emp I only get the hard coded HTML   tags.

**I would like to display employees ID, First Name and Last Name in HTML Table via the Flask framework**

**Please see Python code below:**

```
from flask import Flask,  request, render_template
import MySQLdb

app = Flask(__name__)


def db():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                         user="someone",
                         passwd="something",
                         db="inventory" )

    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_Name from employees")

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    db.close()

    return rows
    

rows = db()

for row in rows:
    #print(row)
    print str(row[0]) + " - " + row[1] + " " + row[2]

@app.route('/emp', methods=['GET'])
def emp():
        
    return render_template ('inventory.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

**Here is the HTML Template**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <title>Inventory Database</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { background-color: white; }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="body">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3 class="text-primary">Inventory Management Database: All Employees </h3>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th> 
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>              
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>1</th> 
                <th>Alex</th>
                <th>Smith</th>      
            </tr>
        
            {% for emp in employees %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ID}}</td>
                    <td>{{First_Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{Last_Name}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        
            
                                    
                  
        </table>
        
    </div>  
   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, read the [official flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/views/) which explains this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the variable `row` from the template, you have to pass it when you call `render_template`.
Just add the parameters after the view name.

```
return render_template ('inventory.html', employees = rows)
```

Check the doc: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Comment: Thank you tete0148 ... the webpage looks better now, it has rows, but they are just blank rows with no data from the database

Comment: You need to debug the the rows variable to check what's in it. When done, just modify your code in inventory.html to access the correct objet properties

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line below,

**From:** `print str(row[0]) + " - " + row[1] + " " + row[2]`

**To** print `str(row[0] + " - " + row[1] + " " + row[2])`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this as below:

```
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
      {% for row in employees %}
            <tr>
              <td>
                        <span class="custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                            <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                        </span>
              </td>
                <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
                <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
              <td>
```